# Rails Partial Rendering for static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

I am building a personal website on Rails 3.2
It is almost a static website with a bit of `javascript` interactivity and few Db operations.

I was wondering, will it make any difference in my app if I use `partials` for static content?
Or should I include all the static content in just a single page ?

Comment: you can use partials if two pages have the same content. A suggestion, checkout rails caching techniques make the website faster. eg you can use page caching for pages where the content never changes and if the action rendering the page doens't need authentication and doesnt have filters.

Comment: I think partials use the same rendering engine as "standard" Rails pages - meaning you can call them at will, and they'll just show in your view. Nothing wrong with using them at all - you'll just need to structure your system to make it worth calling them